# High volume ASP page calling an ASP.NET to leverage cache results in 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, http-status-code-503, http.sys, httpcontext.cache

A high volume classic ASP page is using an ASP.NET page to return xml data, taking advantage of .NET caching capabilities. The cache being used in the .net page is the Context Cache. Recently after 1 year of running smoothly - IIS7 starts responding with a 503 unavailable and in the HTTP.sys error log it displays a few connection_dropped events, then a slew of connection_dropped_list_full events. At this point the servers is unavailable.

Looking at possibilities of having hit a cache limitation or a network problem.

Comment: I have no idea how you could expect anyone to solve the problem for you. _You_ have access to the code, but we do not.

Comment: Question states that this has been running for 1 year without an issue, no code changes have been made and I am really looking to see if anyone has come across the connection dropped list full error in IIS and what they have attributed it to.  As for the code, it's nothing complicated - a context.cache.insert is being used when the object is created from a db call.

Comment: That is indeed what I was looking for when asking this question - that someone had a similar set up and had seen this issue.  Nevertheless there is enough lack of information on the web regarding this condition that we will open a ticket with MS.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?